# Same index value in each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I am writing a script that will automatically fill input item with its index value.

So far I have written this:

```
$('body').append($("<input>", {type: "button", id: "numeruj", value: "Numeruj"}));
var $numery = $('input[id*="FileDescriptionTextBox"]');


$("#numeruj").click(function(){
    $numery.each(function(index){
   $numery.val(index)
})
})
```

The problem is that each item is assigned the same index value which is basically $numery.length.
I can't figure out why each item is not assigned its own index.
Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: `.click` will works with the elements which are already present in DOM, use `.on` which will work for dynamic generated DOM elements

Comment: I'm not sure about it but have you tried to replace id with class ?

Comment: no need to have the each loop, `$numery.val(function (index) {
        return index;
    })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` inside each block. the keyword `this` refers to the element

Use

```
$("#numeruj").click(function() {
    $numery.each(function(index) {
        $(this).val(index); //You need to use this
    })
})
```

Comment: `this.value = index` would do the trick too without the extra function calls, however the jQuery way is better if `select` and other more complex tags are used.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. I tried using this but did not think about wrapping it in jquery object. I assumed that in this case this keyword already refers to the jquery object. Does it instead refer to standard js element?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using $numery it will set index for all one value as you're defining at previous line.

Use `$(this)` instead of `$numery` inside the each function:

```
$("#numeruj").click(function(){
    $numery.each(function(index){
      $(this).val(index)
    })
})
```